# Vue.js 2.0 transition on dynamic route not firing

Tags: javascript, transition, vue.js, vue-router

I found that transition is not firing on dynamic route with parameters. For exemple with the code below, when I am in `/chapter/1` and I go to `/chapter/2` there is no transition. But when I am in `/chapter/1` and I go to `/profile/1` there is one !

`main.js` file

```
require('normalize.css')

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'
import Panel from './components/Panel'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

window.bus = new Vue()

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
     { path: '/', redirect: '/chapter/1' },
     { name:'chapter', path: '/chapter/:id', component: Panel},
     { name:'profile', path: '/profile/:id', component: Profile}
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

`App.vue` template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>

    <div class="controls">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'chapter', params: { id: Math.max(1, parseInt($route.params.id) - 1) }}">
        Prev
      </router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'chapter', params: { id: parseInt($route.params.id) + 1 }}">
        Next
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Maybe is due to the fact that vue-router doesn't destroy the parent component ? I didn't found a way to run the transition from the code. I tried this configuration on [vue-router example pack](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/examples) and the behavior is the same.

---

quote from the [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.
>
> To react to params changes in the same component, you can simply watch the $route object

---

Should I post an issue ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you check this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/dLnz4rbL/

I attempted to use the method described under [Transitioning Between Elements](http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements) in the docs.

In my fiddle example, which mostly uses the code from your question description, I used a `transition` wrapper within component, as shown below:

```html
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div class="page-contents" :key="$route.params.id">
        This is my chapter component. Page: {{parseInt($route.params.id)}}
    </div>
</transition>
```

The document specifies that we need to provide a `key` to make them *distinct elements* for Vue.js. So I added your chapter ID as key.

I don't know if this is a hack or a proper solution, I moved from Angular2 to Vue only 2 weeks ago. But till someone gives you a better solution, you may use this method to get your transitions for dynamic routes.

Regarding posting this as an issue in github page of `vue-router`, I am not sure if this qualifies to be addressed / fixed, but you may definitely bring it to their notice. Fix may involve **not reusing** components, which is also not ideal. So it is a tough call for them. But the discussion should definitely be interesting! Please post back the issue link here if you decide to create one :-)

Comment: Hey Mani, 
thanks for your help, I'll look into your solution which works ! There is discussions about this on github if you want to check > https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/751

I'll answer you when I'll get a solution

Comment: @GeorgeAbitbol Thanks for the github issue link! I have posted my question there, with reference to the working jsFiddle example - whether this is a proper method or a hack.

Comment: your idea actually solves my problem, thank you for that ! Maybe there is a link with [`<transition-group>`](http://vuejs.org/api/#transition-group) ?

Comment: I did not know about `<transition-group>` till now. After reading the docs, I think it can be useful for list rendering context where you might want to add / remove few items together. But I would still prefer to use the regular `<transition>` with an enclosing `<div>` as it keeps the DOM clean - there are no additional DOM elements rendered, giving you greater control over what you want. Maybe `<transition-group>` can be helpful in specific contexts, which I am not able to visualize now.

Comment: BTW, I still don't have any response for the comment I posted on that github issue link. I would like to assume that this is a real solution and not just a hack, till we can find a better method :-)

Answer (score 9):

Came here with the same problem and @Mani's answer works fine.
But I don't really like the idea of using two `<transition>`s.

So I tried putting the `key` in `<router-view>` instead. And it works!
Working example: https://codepen.io/widyakumara/details/owVYrW/

Not sure if this the proper vue-way of doing things, I'm kinda new using vue.

PS. I'm using Vue 2.4.1 & Vue Router 2.7.0

Comment: Nice, simple solution. Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: I don't know why, but this works very good with vue@2.5.22
and vue-router@3.0.2. Good job wikyakumara