# How to bind an event on a vue-router template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've been following a guide to create a vue-router object, but the browser displays the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "auth_login" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.  (found in anonymous component -
>   use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)

I just added an event binding on a html tag, like the following:

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view>
    </router-view>

    <script type="text/temptlate" id="t_auth">
        <div class="auth">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/temptlate" id="t_auth_login">
        <div class="auth_login">
            <div>
                <button class="btn-primary full" id="btn_login" @click="auth_login" @keyup.enter="auth_login">登录</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

The JS code is:

```
(function() {
let getView = (id) => {
    tmp = document.getElementById(id)
    if (tmp == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return tmp.innerHTML
};

const routes = [{
    path: '/auth',
    component: { template: getView('t_auth') },
    children: [
        { path: 'register', component: { template: getView('t_auth_register') } },
    ]
}];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    router: router,
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        name: 'Vue.js'
    },
    // 在 `methods` 对象中定义方法
    methods: {
        auth_login: function(event) {
            // 方法内 `this` 指向 vm
            alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app')
})();
```

Why can't it find the `auth_login` method? What about the lifecycle?

How can I bind the event inside the template ?

The full source code is located there: https://github.com/295421489/reminder-ximu/tree/dev/public

Comment: Before attempting to capture templates using innerHTML() from inside script tags, have you tried writing actual route components? That might be simpler to debug... Also you need not do `.$mount("#app")` if you are already specifying `el: "#app"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer for your question, but this is how you can debug your Vue apps:

Install https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools in your Google Chrome browser. You may need to restart the browser for the extension to start working. (I don't remember how I got it the first time)

Once you have Vue dev tools, you will start seeing this in your developer console, whenever you load a Vue app (development build of Vue.js):

[image]

Your routes will also show up very well. As you can see, my app above is currently in the route `/chapter/1` (that orange box on the left side)

Click on "Send to Console" and the `$vm` instance will become available in your developer console.

[image]

Here, you can find if your `auth_login` method is available or not, for your route. And you can also do a lot more debugging for your app.

If you want a working Vue app (with routes) to test, you will find a jsFiddle in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215123/654825

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question.

The error is can't find the method,I think it is because of scope. So, I created a component firstly:

```
var t_auth_login = Vue.extend({
    template: getView('t_auth_login'),
    // 在 `methods` 对象中定义方法
    methods: {
        auth_login: function(event) {
    }
});
```

and the routes values as :

```
const routes = [{
path: '/auth',
component: t_auth}]
```

everything is ok.