# How do you realize the "in-out mode" transition effect when using dynamic route matching in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Is it possible to make the transition effect operate in "in-out mode" by dynamic route matching of Vue.js?
I would like to have a professor if possible.
When I had this trouble, I was able to find very useful questions and answers.

[Vue.js 2.0 transition on dynamic route not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137100/vue-js-2-0-transition-on-dynamic-route-not-firing)

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <div class="page-contents" :key="$route.params.id">
    This is my chapter component. Page: {{parseInt($route.params.id)}}
  </div>
</transition>
```

As shown in the answer, we were able to successfully fire the transition effect by specifying the key for the transition target.
However, I would like to be able to realize with `mode = "in-out"` instead of `mode = "out-in"`.

I would like to be able to superimpose Vue components like the official guide.

[Vue.js Transition Modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes)

> Simultaneous entering and leaving transitions aren’t always desirable though, so Vue offers some alternative transition modes:
> in-out: New element transitions in first, then when complete, the current element transitions out.
> out-in: Current element transitions out first, then when complete, the new element transitions in.

Is it impossible to display one Vue component (instance) at the same time on the screen at the same time?
We are waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use `in-out` with `router-view`, Here is the modified fiddle from the question you have added : https://jsfiddle.net/dLnz4rbL/3/

I have change the transition to `slide-fade` with below CSS:

```
/* Enter and leave animations can use different */
/* durations and timing functions.              */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active for <2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(500px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to move safely! I spent a day to realize this. I have to study more ... By changing to `slide-fade` we were able to issue one component at the same time! Also, by applying absolute coordinates to `router-view` we could overlay components! 
I am very grateful.

Comment: @kaito.higa Glad it helped, I will request to add modified fiddle here, which can help someone else looking at this question.